# Program ignoring "If Else" and printing everything

Tags: java, bluej

I'm trying to create a Random Number Generator program which tracks a player's wins, losses, winning percentage and total winnings. The logic of the program is that a player gets 3 chances per session and the computer generates a random number which the player needs to guess or rather should match.

I've tried to use if & else statements to tell the user if he needs to guess a higher number or a lower number within the 3 allowed guesses. What's happening is that it completely ignores the conditions and prints all three chances at once and ends the game.

Any inputs on this would be highly appreciated.

Game Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

    Player player;
    LuckyNumberGenerator lng;

    public Game() {
        player = new Player();
        lng = new LuckyNumberGenerator();
    }

    public void eventLoop() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = 0;
        boolean exit = false;
        while (!exit) {
            System.out.println("Welcome to the Guessing Game");
            System.out.println("==============================");
            System.out.println("(1) Set Up New Player");
            System.out.println("(2) Play One Round");
            System.out.println("(3) Player Win Statistics");
            System.out.println("(4) Display Game Help");
            System.out.println("(5) Exit Game");
            System.out.println("Choose an option: ");

            try {
                choice = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
                if (choice < 1 || choice > 5) {
                    System.err.println("Error : Choose an option between 1 and 5");
                    choice = 0;
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.err.println("Error : Choose an option between 1 and 5");
                choice = 0;
            }

            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    createNewPlayer(scanner);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    guessNumber(scanner);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    printStatistics();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    printHelp();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    exit = true;
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

    public void printHelp() {
        System.out.println(" ");
    }

    public void printStatistics() {
        try {
            if (player.getName() == null || player.getName().trim().length() < 1) {
                System.out.println("Player has not been set up!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Player statistics are: ");
                System.out.println("Name: " + player.getName());
                System.out.println("Wins: " + player.getGamesWon());
                System.out.println("Losses: " + player.getGamesLost());
                System.out.println("Amount won so far: " + player.getTotalWinnings());
                System.out.println("Winnings percentage : "
                        + (((player.getGamesWon()) / (player.getGamesWon() + player.getGamesLost())) * 100));
            }
        } catch (ArithmeticException ae) {
            System.out.println("wins and loss both are 0: divide by zero exception");
        }
    }

    public void guessNumber(Scanner scanner) {
        int compGuess = lng.generate();
        int userGuess = 0;
        int numAttempts = 0;
        int cnum = lng.generateConsole();
        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("Guess a number between 1-100: ");
                userGuess = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
                if (userGuess < 1 || userGuess > 100) {
                    System.err.println("Error : your Guess must be between 1-100");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error : your Guess must be between 1-100");
            }
        } while (userGuess < 1 && userGuess > 100);
        do {
            if (userGuess > compGuess) {
                System.out.println("Your Guess is: " + userGuess + "and the random number: " + compGuess);
                System.out.println("Sorry, you need to go LOWER  :");
            } else if (userGuess < compGuess) {
                System.out.println("Your Guess is: " + userGuess + "and the random number: " + compGuess);
                System.out.println("Sorry, you need to go HIGHER  :");
            }
            numAttempts++;

            if (userGuess == compGuess) {
                System.out.println("Lucky Number was : " + compGuess + "your  guess was : " + userGuess);
                System.out.println("Congratulations you won " + 10 + "$");
                player.setGamesWon(1);
                player.setTotalWinnings(10);
            }

            if (userGuess != compGuess && (userGuess <= (compGuess + 5)) && (userGuess >= (compGuess - 5))) {
                System.out.println("Lucky Number was : " + compGuess + "your FINAL guess was : " + userGuess);
                System.out.println("Congratulations you won " + cnum + "$");
                player.setTotalWinnings(5);
            } else if (userGuess != compGuess) {
                System.out.println("Lucky Number was : " + compGuess + "your  guess was : " + userGuess);
                System.out.println("Sorry better Luck Next time");
                player.setGamesLost(1);
                player.setTotalWinnings(-1);
            }
        } while (userGuess != compGuess && numAttempts < 3);
    }

    public void createNewPlayer(Scanner scanner) {
        String name = null;
        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter the name of the player: ");
                name = scanner.nextLine();
                if (name.isEmpty()) {
                    System.err.println("Name cannot be empty");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        } while (name.isEmpty());
        this.player = new Player(name);
    }

    public static void main() {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.eventLoop();
    }

}
```

Comment: I highly doubt that it´s ignoring the `else if` and that it´s rather a logical flaw ;) Also formatting your code would make it a lot easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for your input Kevin. It is a logical flaw indeed but not quite getting where I'm going wrong. I'm new to Java and this is my very first program. I tried a few possibilities but it doesn't seem to be working. Any thoughts would be great. Sorry for the bad formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
do {
        try {
            System.out.println("Guess a number between 1-100: ");
            userGuess = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
            if (userGuess < 1 || userGuess > 100) {
                System.err.println("Error : your Guess must be between 1-100");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error : your Guess must be between 1-100");
        } 
    } while(userGuess < 1 && userGuess > 100);//incorrect

//correct condition -> while(userGuess < 1 || userGuess > 100);
```

a number cannot be less than 1 and greater than 100 at the same time.

Edit 1 : In your 2nd loop the following two condition

```
1) if (userGuess != compGuess && (userGuess <= (compGuess + 5))
            && (userGuess >= (compGuess - 5))) 

2)else if (userGuess != compGuess)
```

should only be evaluated if the number of guesses by player exceeds the number of attempts, therefore the two if conditions should be written outside the loop.

Also you need the first while loop to keep the user input valid between 1-100, And your second while loop will be inside it.

The final code will look something like this.

```
    do {

        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("Guess a number between 1-100: ");
                userGuess = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
                if (userGuess < 1 || userGuess > 100) {
                    System.err
                            .println("Error : your Guess must be between 1-100");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err
                        .println("Error : your Guess must be between 1-100");
            }
        } while (userGuess < 1 || userGuess > 100);

        System.out.println(" " + userGuess);

        if (userGuess > compGuess) {
            System.out.println("Your Guess is: " + userGuess
                    + "and the random number: " + compGuess);
            System.out.println("Sorry, you need to go LOWER  :");

        }
        if (userGuess < compGuess) {
            System.out.println("Your Guess is: " + userGuess
                    + "and the random number: " + compGuess);
            System.out.println("Sorry, you need to go HIGHER  :");
            System.out.println("if 1");
        }
        numAttempts++;

        if (userGuess == compGuess) {
            System.out.println("Lucky Number was : " + compGuess
                    + "your  guess was : " + userGuess);
            System.out.println("Congratulations you won " + 10 + "$");
            // player.setGamesWon(1);
            // player.setTotalWinnings(10);

        }

    } while (userGuess != compGuess & numAttempts < 3);

    if (userGuess != compGuess && (userGuess <= (compGuess + 5))
            || (userGuess >= (compGuess - 5))) {
        System.out.println("Lucky Number was : " + compGuess
                + " your FINAL guess was : " + userGuess);
        // System.out.println("Congratulations you won " + cnum + "$");
        // player.setTotalWinnings(5);

    } else if (userGuess != compGuess) {
        System.out.println("Lucky Number was : " + compGuess
                + "your  guess was : " + userGuess);
        System.out.println("Sorry better Luck Next time");
        // player.setGamesLost(1);
        // player.setTotalWinnings(-1);

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I removed the condition altogether. The problem is with the second do while loop.

Comment: modifying the answer 1 sec

Comment: @ArvindSuryanarayana check my answer if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the first do-while in the second do-while at the top.

Comment: Tried that but still the same issue. It prints out everything after the first guess.

Comment: Can you post the output? And your input

Comment: Chose Option 2 > Entered 4 > Came up with: "Your Guess is 4 and the random number is 48" > "You need to go higher" > "Lucky number was 48 and your guess was 4" > "Sorry better luck next time".

Comment: Try putting numAttempts++ IN the first two ifs/if else, and change all other ifs to if else.

Comment: Thanks for that. I does do it 3 times but ignores `else if (userGuess != compGuess) {
                    System.out.println("Lucky Number was : " + compGuess
                    + "your  guess was : " + userGuess);
                    System.out.println("Sorry better Luck Next time");
                    player.setGamesLost(1);
                    player.setTotalWinnings(-1);`

Comment: That's because you already check for (userGuess != compGuess) with if (userGuess > compGuess) and if (userGuess < compGuess). You would have to replace  else if(userGuess != compGuess) with else if(userGuess != compGuess && numAttempts == 3). Edit: Oh and of course you need to change  if (userGuess > compGuess) and if (userGuess < compGuess) to  if (userGuess > compGuess && numAttempts < 3) and if (userGuess < compGuess && numAttempts < 3)

Comment: Did that but still ignores it. By the way, i've put numAttempts++ only in the first two if else statements.

Comment: Did you take the edit into account in my last comment? If yes I am out ouf ideas sorry :/

Comment: Yes I did do that but still ignores it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Okay last idea. Change numAttempts == 3 to numAttempts == 2 and numAttempts < 3 to numAttempts < 2 etc

Answer (score 0):

```
while(userGuess < 1 && userGuess > 100);
        do{
```

This contains the error. The loop should run while the userGuess is between 1 and 100, you have excluded it.

It should be

```
while(userGuess >= 1 && userGuess <= 100);
        do{
```

Comment: Thanks for that. But this is just for the first loop and that is running fine. It's the second one that I'm having problems with.

Comment: Forgive me for being too lazy to try myself, but does that work even though it has a semicolon?

Comment: Ah nevermind. That `while` is completely unrelated to the `do` below it.

Answer (score 0):

**AND** condition needs to be changed to an **OR** condition. Because you want to loop only when the user inputs something lower than 1 or higher than 100.

```
while(userGuess < 1 && userGuess > 100);  ===> while(userGuess < 1 || userGuess > 100);
```

Again, another **AND** needs to be changed to **OR**.

```
// Issue with logic
if (userGuess != compGuess && (userGuess <= (compGuess + 5)) &&
               (userGuess >= (compGuess - 5))) {

// Corrected Code
if (userGuess != compGuess && (userGuess <= (compGuess + 5)) ||
               (userGuess >= (compGuess - 5))) {
```